# Static methods in Interfaces in Java

Tags: java

```
 interface TestInterface
 {
    public static void square(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("Square is "+a*a);
    }

    public static  void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Default Method Executed");
    }

 }
class TestClass implements TestInterface
{
    public void square(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a*a);
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Overridden Method");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestClass d=new TestClass();
        d.square(4);
        TestInterface.square(4);
        TestInterface.show();
        d.show();
    }
}
```

I have a doubt in my code. I learnt that static methods cannot be overridden in JAVA, but it seems to be working fine here.
When i give both default and static keywords together, like this

```
interface TestInterface
   {
        default static void square(int a)
        {
            System.out.println("Square is "+a*a);
        }

        public static  void show()
        {
            System.out.println("Default Method Executed");
        }

    }
```

An error crops up as follows:
**illegal combination of modifiers: static and default**

What is the reason for JAVA treating this as an error?

Comment: The static methods are **shadowed** not overridden.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @Code-Apprentice, what do you mean by the words "Shadowed and not overridden"? Does the compiler treat the static and non static methods as two completely different entities? Even if they have same signature?

Comment: Try that prior research thing the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` method is meant to be called without an instance of the class/interface concerned.  Usually they are meant to be utility methods.

A `default` method is meant to be called on an instance of the interface concerned.  All implementations of this interface will have this method definition, unless it is overridden.

The reason these two terms are not allowed together is simply because they contradict each other: `default` requires an object, `static` requires no object.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Clarified my doubts:)

Answer (score 0):

`TestClass.show()` and `TestClass.square()` are not `static` and therefore do not override the `static` methods in the interface. They are member methods and require an object to call them. On the other hand, the methods with the same name in the interface are `static` and so you can call them with the interface name or class name without an object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It solved my doubts:)